# I want to separate values into different columns based on a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt file with / as a delimiter.

The input file looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
DATE / yyyy-mm-dd / TIME / xx:yy
DATA / NOMINAL / ACTUAL / TOLERANCE / DEVIATION
SIZE K / 38.05 / 38.0472 / 0.05 / -0.0028
POSN Y / 0 / 0.0025 / 0 / 0.0025
----------------------------------------------...
DATE / yyyy-mm-dd / TIME / xx:yy
K1 / 70 / PICKER
DATA / NOMINAL / ACTUAL / TOLERANCE / DEVIATION
SIZE K / 8 / 8.0989 / 0.2 / 0.0989
POSN Y / 0 / -0.0246 / 0 / -0.0246
```

I'm interested in line 4 & 5 where line 4 should be the header corresponding to the values and text in row 5 (Data corresponds to SIZE K, NOMINAL corresponds to 38.05 etc.). The same goes for row 9, 10 and 11 where row 9 should act as a header for the two rows below it.

I tried importing it using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'<path>', sep='/')
```

But it gives the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 4, saw 6
```

Comment: you have an inconsistent number of fields

Comment: Please provide the matching expected output for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brute forced it a bit, I guess there can be a better way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'Data.txt' # path to file
data = list() #  init list
with open(file_path, 'r') as file: # read file
    lines = file.readlines() # read lines
    for line in lines: # for each line
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        if '/' in line: # check if it has /
            lineFields = line.strip().split('/') # split according to " / "
            if (lineFields not in data) and (len(lineFields) == 5): # if we have 5 fields and if not already inside
                data.append(lineFields) # append

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]) # create the dataframe with the first row as header
df['newIndex'] = df['DATA'] + '_' + (df.groupby('DATA').cumcount()+1).astype(str) # grouping
df.set_index("newIndex", inplace = True, drop = True) # set data as index and drop
df.drop('DATA', axis = 1, inplace = True) # drop DATA..
print(df) # results...
```

The results:

```
         NOMINAL   ACTUAL TOLERANCE DEVIATION
newIndex                                     
SIZEK_1    38.05  38.0472      0.05   -0.0028
POSNY_1        0   0.0025         0    0.0025
SIZEK_2        8   8.0989       0.2    0.0989
POSNY_2        0  -0.0246         0   -0.0246
```

Comment: Wow that was impressive! Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not that great, I just noticed that now you have duplicates in the index. I'll edit an adjustment

Comment: What if I would like to do this for a number of files which are all of the same type? I have imported the filenames as a series and I would like to run through them and ad them all to a single dataframe so that the filename corresponds to the data for each file?

Comment: @Holmbrero all is possible, but I guess that is another question (or better, check google, there are a lot of these examples, just use a loop to go through the files in `os.listdir(yourPath)`

Comment: @Holmbrero please remember to close the question if this worked for you

Comment: @Holmbrero also, please check the last edit. Here the sizek and posny are also grouped (1, 2, etc...)